# In Excel13 how to get count of adjacent non-blank unique records

Tags: excel-2013

Below is my data in excel. I want to find for values in ColA how many distinct non-blank values (Count) present in ColB
[image]

In a separate column I have Unique values from ColA for that Column I want to find unique values present in ColB
I want output:

[image: ColA | Result 1 | 2 2 | 1 3 | 3]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with something like this
If my adjacent columns are L and M

```
=COUNTIFS(L3:L8,"=1",M3:M8,"")
=COUNTIFS(L3:L8,"=2",M3:M8,"")
=COUNTIFS(L3:L8,"=3",M3:M8,"")
```

Comment: This is giving me count of blank cells. I don't want to count blank cells. I want unique values excluding blank.